# The Package Manager Console in Visual Studio is not displaying the command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am currently doing my homework for a class in ASP.Net. We're focusing on MVC and I was doing fine until the next task. The step was to: "open the Package Manager Console. At the command prompt, enter the 'Add-Migration Initial'command. This should add a Migrations folder and migration files to the Solution Explorer,". I did that but did not get any command prompt displaying... Any help or tips for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no error explaining what is wrong about opening Package Manager. I suggest you to use **.Net Core Cli**

you can try opening **command prompt screen** under your project and issue

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```